# Is it possible to use aab and apk in same release in GooglePlay?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

For example:

```
API 16-20 : 4 split by ABI APKs

API 21+   : appbundle
```

I need this, because I don't support 16-20 anymore and use old release for them. https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#HowItWorks

I know, I can try it myself, but I'm unable to test this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have a mix of APKs and App Bundles in the same release.

If I understand correctly, you want to upload App Bundles for new versions, but carry over APKs from previous releases for devices that you no longer support. That is a common use-case and is indeed supported.